# How to merge a remote branch into my current branch, but only stage the changes so I can evaluate and unstage them as I want?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

How to merge a remote branch into my current branch, but be able to see the file changes as staged changes in git. This happens sometimes, and I can edit in VSCode, but other times it automatically merges everything in.

When working in a branch I want to merge a remote branch into, I run:

```
git pull origin branch-name
```

depending on how different my working branch and this remote branch are, sometimes it stages, other times it just merges directly in.

How can I reliably get the staging to happen? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can ask `git merge` (which is implied in your `git pull` command) to wait for your approval (after potential edits) with the [`--no-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull/en#Documentation/git-pull.txt---no-commit) option.

Important note from the doc :

> Note that fast-forward updates do not create a merge commit and therefore there is no way to stop those merges with --no-commit. Thus, if you want to ensure your branch is not changed or updated by the merge command, use --no-ff with --no-commit.

---

So, the full process would be

```
git pull --no-commit --no-ff origin branch-name

# check whatever you need at this point, edit files, run things
# (don't forget to add paths you modified)
# and when you're ready :

git merge --continue
# or just (same effect)
git commit
```

...which will prompt the commit message in your editor with the automatic merge info prepared (which you can edit too).